# ADB Bluestacks - Connect 2 PC

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

I've two PCs, say PC1 and PC2. I've Bluestacks installed in PC1 and I've Android Studio Installed in PC2. So my question is : "Is it possible to connect to the Bluestacks emulator through the ADB installed in PC2 ?" So that I can install the application from PC1 to PC2's bluestacks.

NOTE: PC1 and PC2 are on the same network.

Comment: try this command look if helps `adb connect ip-address-of-pc2:5555`

Comment: Negative. adb says : Unable to connect to ip-address-of-pc2:5555

Comment: dude in place of `ip-address-of-pc2` insert ip address of your pc2

Comment: Haha, that's what i done man. i just modified the comment for your preference.

Comment: then m sorry its not possible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect an `adb` hosted on a **remote computer** to a `Bluestacks` running on the **local computer**,  you can try.:

**The problem:**

Bluestacks listens on the **localhost interface only** (`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`), it doesn't listen on ex: `192.168.1.4`. Based on this, and at first, you cannot connect remotely to Bluestacks using `ADB`.

**The solution:**

Internal Port forwarding

**How to:**

1 - Download [trivial_portforward.zip](http://www.quantumg.net/trivial_portforward.zip) | [mirror](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shGlgv0NG1ZfYsAVraEEjls0qmyVuzO0/)

2 - On the **computer running Bluestacks**, run:

```
trivial_portforward.exe 9999 127.0.0.1 5555
//usage: portforward [port to listen on] [ip of host to connect to] [port to connect to].
```

3 - On the **computer running Eclipse or Android Studio**, run:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.4:9999 
//Connected to 192.168.1.4 9999
```

(change to the ip of the computer running Bluestacks)

That's it.

**Notes:**
Make sure the **firewall** isn't blocking outgoing/incoming connections  on both computers.
I've tested deploying an application and it works :)

Comment: You could also setup a ssh server on pc2 and use a ssh client on pc1 that sets up a ssh tunnel ... that way you have something works whenever you wish to access a local port on some remote device that you can login to.  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/

Comment: Do you have any idea about the `Genymotion` ? i mean how can i connect to the Genymotion of one pc from another pc on the same network? @Pedro Labito

Comment: Genymotion isn't working on my computer so I've no way to help you :(, the logic should be the same, give it a try.

Comment: It seems this method is not valid for another ports. I.e: if you install some SSH server on BlueStacks, nothing is found listening on the host machine on port 22 whan issuing `netstat -ano | find "22"`. Tested too with another ports above 1024.

Comment: If the `ssh server`, or any other server, isn't listening on BlueStacks there's nothing you can do, this has nothing to do with port forward.

Comment: @PedroLobito Now am working in `Ubuntu`, so.. Do you know how to port_forward in ubuntu  like we did in windows ?

Comment: Use iptables to forward ports